# Which iFrame property let Youtube video unmute be default?

Tags: iframe

ok,iframe, which holds youtube video, has a property `allowfullscreen`. Ex: `<iframe  src=videoUrl allowfullscreen></iframe>`

My question is that :

does it have "`unmute`" property so that the video will never be unmuted at the beginning of the loading process?

Or

Does iFrame has a property that let Youtube video unmute be default?

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve here, can you clarify?

Comment: How to let youtube video unmute by default?

Answer (score 0):

```
player = new YT.Player(currentVideoId, {
                events: {
                    'onReady': onPlayerReady
                }
            });
function onPlayerReady(event) {
    event.target.mute();
    event.target.playVideo()
}
```